# Laravel: How to include external links in selected views

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i have included all the  css and js external links under `<header>` tag of my index view.

Now there are some external links which i want to `load on selected views only`,

i can add links separately on that view but `that link will go out of <head> tag`.

how can i load selected links on selected views only from `<header> tag of index view`.

i tried

```
<head>
...other links
     @if(View::exists('ispblade.calendar'))
            @include('ispblade.calendar_links')
        @endif 
</head>
```

but it's loading selected link on `all views`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `stacks` for that.

In Layout:

```
<head>
    <!-- Head Contents -->

    @stack('scripts')
</head>
```

In your view:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks

Comment: i also want to add css files it's not working, method is it same for both js/css?

Comment: Of course it will work for it as well. Create another stack for example css like `@stack('css)`